# How to make lights in eevee not react to volumetrics?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, visibility

I have a scene with heavy volumetric scattering in eevee, and i'm lighting my main object with a point light.  I want to keep the effects of the light hitting the object, but I want to elminate the light's effect on the scene's volumetrics.  Is this possible in eevee?

Thanks!